# Alternative to wcf callback.Is there one?

Tags: wcf

Wondering if there is a better option than a wcf callback.

When processing some data Invoices and printing them and I need to constantly show the user in a winform -"Invoice 1 Printed" invoice 2 printed etc....
I have put together a call back mechanism and all works but wondering if there is a better way of doing this .

Was thinking along the line if 2 services would be better than a callback.
One that loops at server side through the invoices and saves to the database the status ="Printed" and the other the queries it and check if it has printed and return to the user
.

Would that be better than a callback,faster and avoid timeouts etc..?

Just thinking as an alternative as a collegue who used callback extensively said" dont use callback use 2 services".

What would you do if you had to process 2000 invoices and notify the user for each one

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'better'. I'm not sure why you would regard two services as better than using a callback. Under the covers it's pretty much the identical mechanisms being used, it's just simpler to connect up the endpoints. There's no fundamental reason I'm aware of for it to be faster or behave any differently in respect of timeouts. Can you clarify? 2000 callbacks would be pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On one project we have done the following:

- All windows clients also host a WCF service
- When the windows client starts it registers itself with the server, that this user is loggon with this IP address.
- The server stores info on who is logged in where
- Then we can send a message to the user whenever we want

When the client recieves the message we fire an event, then whatever part of the UI that is affected can update itself or show a message.

Comment: That's pretty much how WCF Duplex (callbacks) works, but with much more edge cases an particular details covered. Why reinvent the wheel ? (and worse)

Comment: No it is not duplex, apart from on call in the morning, the client does not need to make any calls.